# Backgroundworker and Task.Run have a big delay before action

Tags: c#, task, backgroundworker

Have 1 main `BackgroundWorker` and many of other. In time of starting other workers in main worker `Task.Run` not running in expected time.
How to modify code to do all tasks(or threads) parallel?

```
static List<System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker> workers;
static System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker mainWorker;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    mainWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    mainWorker.DoWork += MainWorker_DoWork;
    mainWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    workers = new List<System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        workers.Add(new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker());
        workers[i].DoWork += FastAnalizWorker_DoWork;
        workers[i].RunWorkerAsync(i);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}

static void MainWorker_DoWork(object sender,
    System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Task.Run(() => ShowMessage("main"));
    }
}

static void FastAnalizWorker_DoWork(object sender,
    System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int index = (int)e.Argument;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(index * 1000);
    ShowMessage(index.ToString());
}

static void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:mm ss}: {1}", DateTime.UtcNow, message));
}
```

Console result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKg2T.jpg)

Comment: You are conflating two APIs on Threading here. Do not. Use Backgroundworker or Tasks. Not both. This is asking for desaster.

Comment: Could you try adding this line at the start of the program, and see if it makes any difference? `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` This is not suggested as a fix, but as a way to troubleshoot the issue that you are observing.

Comment: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100); ` helped

Comment: Then Jesús López's answer is to the point.

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Run` have a big delay because you are causing thread pool starvation.

Both `BackgroundWorker` and `Task.Run` use the thread pool to do their job.

The thread pool starvation is caused because:

- You are calling `Thread.Sleep()` that blocks the current thread.
- You are concurrently running more `BackgroundWorker's` than the thread pool size